# Facebook not scraping correct specific data

Tags: debugging, facebook-opengraph

I've had this problem in the past where FB scrapes the wrong data, but changing the thumbnail image name has always fixed the problem. However, today I'm unable to get the same result. The error is this:

[Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOq1X.png)

I've cleared my browser cache, renamed the image, inserted code at the top of the blog post with the image link, and scraped a dozen times in the debugger. My company uses Placester for our web platform (if that means anything to anyone), so I don't have quite as much freedom as with other sites. Can anyone help me with this, but put it in layman's terms?

Comment: I don't immediatly see anything wrong with the webpage, as I can find the meta properties just fine. Interested to know what's wrong.